# Why Locality meant jointly observable?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, operators, commutator, locality

[Tobias Osborne's lecture around 20:00](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AsO_KUf56_M&list=PLDfPUNusx1Ep5g1jIKXqpNX_t_Zz-kAlQ&index=4), he mentioned that the ideal of "Locality" could be expressed as such

> If $x-y$ were space-like, then for all observable $A_{j,x}$ and $A_{k,y}$ were jointly measurable.

The first index $j$ and $k$ indicate difference different fields/particles, where $x,y\in\mathbb{R}^{p,q}$ the coordinates.

Could you elaborate what he meant by such construction? Was there any difference between jointly measurable and mutually measurable?(i.e. $[A_{j,x},A_{k,y}]=0$)
And why spacelike?

Comment: Related: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/199968/50583